# sqljocky query does not have a method 'then' (dart database access)

Tags: dart, dart-async

I'm trying to code sql access to a database using [sqljocky](http://jamesots.github.io/sqljocky/docs/sqljocky.html) in Dart. As I want to make some computation with the result returned by my database Handler, the method return a Future.

But when I try to run it, I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: The null object does not have a method 'then'`
```

I've ran the debugger and found that this error raise on:

```dart
db.query('select * from user where email="$email"').then(...)
```

but the catchError clause doesn't fire.

My handler method is:

```dart
// db is a ConnectionPool
Future<Map<String,String>> queryUser(String email){
    print(email);
    db.query('select * from user where email="${email}"').then((result) { // here raise the error
        Map<String,String> results = new Map<String,String>();
        result.forEach((row){
           results['status'] = '200'; 
           results['ID'] = row[0];
           results['Image'] = row[1];
           results['Name'] = row[2];
           results['Email'] = row[3];
           results['Password'] = row[4];
        });
        return results;
    }).catchError((error){
        Map<String,String> results = new Map<String,String>();
        results['status'] = '500';
        return results;
    });
}
```

And the method that call this handler is:

```dart
List getUser(String email) {
    Future<Map<String,String>> result = dbhandler.queryUser(email);
    result.then((Map<String,String> result) {
    String statuscode = result['status'];
    result.remove('status');
    String json = JSON.encode(result);
    List pair = new List();
    pair.add(statuscode);
    pair.add(json);
    return pair;
});
```

If I run the query directly in phpmyadmin, it return correct data, so it  is correct.

Can someone give me a hint about how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queryUser() method will always return null, as there is no return statement. In the next release of Dart there will be a static hint warning for this, but at the moment there is none.

Perhaps the code below is what you meant to do. Note the initial return statement before db.query(), and the extra result.toList() call. I haven't tested this, so there's probably a typo or two.

```dart
Future<Map<String,String>> queryUser(String email){
    print(email);
    return db.query('select * from user where email="${email}"')
      .then((result) => result.toList())
      .then((rows) {
        var row = rows.single;
        Map<String,String> results = new Map<String,String>();
        results['status'] = '200'; 
        results['ID'] = row[0];
        results['Image'] = row[1];
        results['Name'] = row[2];
        results['Email'] = row[3];
        results['Password'] = row[4];
        return results;
      }).catchError((error){
        Map<String,String> results = new Map<String,String>();
        results['status'] = '500';
        return results;
      });
}
```

You can also make this a bit cuter using map literals:

```dart
Future<Map<String,String>> queryUser(String email){
    return db.query('select * from user where email="${email}"')
      .then((result) => result.toList())
      .then((rows) => <String, String> {
        'status': '200',
        'ID': rows.single[0],
        'Image': rows.single[1],
        'Name': rows.single[2],
        'Email': rows.single[3],
        'Password': rows.single[4] })
      .catchError((error) => <String, String> {'status': '500'});
}
```

Comment: Thanks Greg, I've just solved it, I will write my answer, it may be helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer using *Completer* to control the *Future* object, but the real problem was, as Greg Lowe said, that my methods doesn't return anything as they come to end before the *then* clause.

Using completer, I've made my query method as:

```dart
Future<Map<String,String>> queryUser(String email){
    Completer c = new Completer(); 
    db.query('select * from user where email="$email"').then((result) {
        Map<String,String> results = new Map<String,String>();
        result.forEach((row){
            results['status'] = '200'; 
            results['ID'] = row[0].toString();
            results['Image'] = row[1];
            results['Name'] = row[2];
            results['Email'] = row[3];
            results['Password'] = row[4];
        }).then((onValue){
            c.complete(results);
        });
    }).catchError((error){
        Map<String,String> results = new Map<String,String>();
        results['status'] = '500';
        c.completeError((e) => print("error en queryUser"));
    });
return c.future;
}
```

I also solved an error when using the *foreach* method, at first I supposed it return nothing, but after that, I noticed that it return a Future, so I added a then clause.

And my getUser method:

```dart
Future<List> getUser(String email) {
    Completer c = new Completer(); 
    Future<Map<String,String>> result = dbhandler.queryUser(email);
    result.then((Map<String,String> result) {
        String statuscode = result['status'];
        result.remove('status');
        String json = JSON.encode(result);
        List pair = new List();
        pair.add(statuscode);
        pair.add(json);
        c.complete(pair); 
    });
    return c.future; 
}
```

After those changes, everything works right

Comment: That solution looks worse than the one form @GregLowe. Why didn't you go the way he suggested? What do you think is the advantage of your solution? Adding `return` (as suggested) has the same effect as adding the `Completer` code.

Comment: There is no important reason to go my way, but, as I am new with Dart and come from Java, my way looks a bit easier to read  for me than the one provided by @GregLowe, so I wanted to write it here also so it can  help anyone in the future.

Comment: It's important to understand how then() calls can be chained together.  Completers are probably simpler to understand at first, but they get hairy once you try and sequence multiple asynchronous operations into a single chain. Chaining then() calls means that error handling works correctly. For example what happens in your example when JSON.encode() throws an exception? I think the error won't be added to the future returned by getUser(), and this will cause your app to crash (Unless you're using zones). To fix this you need an extra try catch, and to pass the error to the completer.